# JPA criteira api for '@>' function

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, psql, criteria-api

How to convert this query in JPA criteria api

```
SELECT * from conditions WHERE value @> '[6,6]'
```

@> means contains. More info:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-range.html

My `conditions` table have `value` whose type is Range

Basically i am not able to get equivalent of @> in JPA criteria api